# Get closed price from a timestamp

Tags: pine-script

The manual talks about how to get timestamp from a candle's closed price, but how do you get a closed price based on timestamp?

Let's say that I want to get the closed price of the 5th candle back from the current candle. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bool already_stored = false

var float price = na
var int ts = na

var label mylabel = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

if barstate.islast and not already_stored
    price := close[5]
    ts := time[5]
    label.set_xy(mylabel, x = ts, y = price)
    already_stored := true
```

Answer (score 0):

The fifth candle back can be referenced using a historical operator [x] following your variable. Eg. Close 5 bars ago is close[5].

Comment: The problem with historical operator is that the [5] changes as new candle forms. I want to get the timestamp on the [5] when the script is initiated and then get the closed price of that particular timestamp.